# Simple jquery cascading selects

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#model").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#category").change(function(){
        $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#type").html("<option>Please wait...</option>");
        var id = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
        $.post("../select_type.php", {id:id}, function(data){
            $("select#type").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#type").html(data);
        });
    });
    $("select#type").change(function(){
        $("select#model").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#model").html("<option>Please wait...</option>");
        var id2 = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');
        $.post("../select_model.php", {id2:id2}, function(data){
            $("select#model").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#model").html(data);
        });
    });
    $("form#select_form").submit(function(){
        var cat = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
        var type = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');
        var model = $("select#model option:selected").attr('value');
        if(cat>0 && type>0 && model >0)
        {
            var model = $("select#model option:selected").html();
            var type = $("select#type option:selected").html();
            $("#result").html('<br>Your choice: ' + type + ' ' + model + '.');
        }
        else
        {
            $("#result").html("<br>You have to fill every field!");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

It is a 3 level cascading dropdown menu system, fetches datas from database with PHP. My problem is, whenever I reach the third level (continents -> countries -> cities for example), and I change the continent to some other or "Not selected" the other 2 levels won't reset. They should be inactive and resetted while the continent select input does not have any value selected. How could I solve this?

Comment: I can't, because I'm getting the datas from database with PHP

Comment: ../select_model.php and ../select_type.php where the datas come from, this script only loads them

Comment: @egyeneskanyar just create with dummy values

Answer (score 0):

in `$("select#category").change()` disable/empty the #model as well, and check for the selected value before doing the ajax request and enabling the #type select.